# How to reccount values from a grid in a cursor

Tags: visual-foxpro

So i have a form with two grids with a different table record source that are related to each other when i use my search grid i create a cursor to display what i have searching. Everything is fine the problem is that the counting of item in the second grid does not count when the cursor is being use it counts  only when the i am not using the cursor in the search textbox how can i count the items in the 2nd grid when i use a cursor in the search textbox.

Ive tried using what i have used in counting normally but it just count the cursor of the first grid value.

Comment: It is almost impossible to understand what you are asking. Probably what you are looking for is simply the reccount() function.